# How can I find and print all of the numbers between two numbers in PHP?

Tags: php, range

Right now I'm asking the user for two numbers. I'm trying to print the numbers in between $one and $two assuming $one is smaller than $two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a simple `for` loop should do the trick:

```
for($i=$a; $i<=$b; $i++) {
  echo $i;
}
```

Answer (score 19):

[`range`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.range.php) gives an array containing all the numbers.

You can iterate over that:

```
foreach (range($one, $two) as $number)
    echo "$number <br>\n";
```

Or simply use a loop:

```
for ($number = $one; $number <= $two; $number++)
    echo "$number <br>\n";
```

Answer (score 5):

```
<?php
foreach (range($one, $two) as $number) {
    echo $number." \n";
}
?>
```

range($one, $two) makes an array of numbers from $one to $two.

```
<?php
$numbers = range($one, $two);
foreach ($numbers as $number) {
    echo $number." \n";
}
?>
```

In this example, the array of numbers are first stored in $numbers before they are printed.

If $one is 5 and $two is 10 these examples will output:

```
5 
6 
7 
8 
9 
10
```

Comment: Range is great, but in this case I think it's a bit overkill to build an array of elements solely to print them out.

Comment: @coreyward - OP did ask to _find_ them as well as print them.

Comment: @aaz I just re-read the question. He didn't mention the word "find" at all. :/

Comment: Also range allows the one liner: `echo implode(',', range($one, $two))`

Comment: He said 'find' in the question title: "How can I `find` and print all of the numbers between two numbers in PHP?"

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like homework...

```
for ($i=$one+1; $i<$two; $i++)
{
  echo $i . "\n";
}
```

This really gets you only the numbers between, not the endpoints.

Answer (score 0):

```
for($i=$one + 1; $i<$two; $i++) {
    echo $i;
}
```