# Split a string using foreach?

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

Is it possible to split a string using foreach?

For example my string value is 10
using foreach echos 1,
then echo 2, 
then echo 3, 
and so on to till it reach the string value.

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/9263106/2943403 , https://stackoverflow.com/q/5033170/2943403 ,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can but looking at what you try to achieve, you really don't need to split instead you are trying to increment using loop till the string value reached. In PHP you can cast string to integer and by default PHP will do that for you if you are trying to perform + - * % / operations.

> Using Foreach

```
$string = '10';
$numbers = range(1, $string);
foreach($numbers as $number){
  echo $number;
}
```

> Using For

```
$string = '10';
for($i = 1; $i <= $string; $i++){
    echo $i;
}
```

If splitting string is what your objective, you can use **str_split()** function and loop like the above **foreach()**